# I can't change version of Web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I downloaded Web3js version 1.0.0 (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases), but

```
var version = web3.version.api;
alert(version);
```

I get 0.20.3 instead of 1.0.0

Why does it happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have two versions of `web3js` installed.

If you installed these `npm`, you can can check with `npm --list | grep web3`

Try uninstalling `0.20.3` like so: `npm uninstall web3@0.20.3`. If version `1.0.0` did not install properly the first time, `npm -i web3@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through `lib/web3.js`, you will see..

`var version = require('./version.json');`

Now if we have a look at `api`

```
this.version = {
    api: version.version
};
```

In this version.json you can see your version..

`"version": "0.20.7"`

Latest : https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/version.json

Take some time to investigate before asking as this isn't really a development question :)

**Edit for clarification** : What you downloaded was a release version.. These are different.. One is a library version, the other is like like a packages release version.